# Problem with installing and running sysdig

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

After the command `apt-get update`, I ran the following command:

```
apt-get -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I got the following errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
```

If I just type `linux-headers` and press Tab to see the options,
it is showing the following:

```
linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-all
linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64
linux-headers-amd64
linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-all-amd64
linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-common
```

So, I replaced the `$(uname -r)` with `4.12.0.kali1-all`
and executed the command. 
After that I ran the following command:

```
apt-get install sysdig
```

Now when I try to run `sysdig`, I get the following error:

```
Unable to load the driver error opening device /dev/sysdig0.
Make sure you have root credentials and that the sysdig-probe module is loaded.
```

**How can I resolve the above issue?**

Currently, the command `uname -a` is showing the following result:

```
Linux kali 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output for `apt-cache search linux-image` is:

```
linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.12.0-kali1-amd64
linux-image-4.12.0-kali1-amd64 - Linux 4.12 for 64-bit PCs
linux-image-4.12.0-kali1-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.12.0-kali1-amd64
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-4.9.0-kali3-amd64 - Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
```

Comment: Have you tried `modprobe sysdig-probe`?

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson. Showing the error
modprobe: FATAL: Module sysdig-probe not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-amd64

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache search linux-image`?

Comment: @GAD3R Search result for the apt-cache search linux-image is edited in the question.

Comment: Try my answer , i have set the exact `linux-image` on the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest `linux-image` package with the appropriate `linux-headers`:

Use : `apt-cache search linux-image` to get the available `linux-image` package e,g:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-4.12.0-kali1-amd64
apt-get install linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64
reboot
apt install dkms sysdig
modprobe sysdig-probe
```

Comment: Should I run apt-get autoremove after all this?

Comment: Why dkms in the install command?